# Displaying the next 6 posts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm looking to create a "related posts" section, but cheating a little by just displaying the next 6 posts in the series on my show.html.erb

How would I go about showing these?

Thanks,

Jon

**EDIT - ADDED POST MODEL**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    belongs_to :user
    is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :view_count

    acts_as_taggable_on :tags

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    scope :featured, -> { where(:featured => true) }

    scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    scope :hot,    -> { order(view_count: :desc) }
    scope :longest, -> { order(duration: :desc) }


    def self.sort_by(sort_param)
      case sort_param
      when 'recent'
        recent
      when 'hot'
        hot
      when 'longest'
        longest
      else
        recent
      end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code for your `Post` model, but assuming it has a `posted_at` attribute and `@post` is currently displayed, you can do:

```
Post.where.not(id: @post.id).order('posted_at desc').limit(6)
```

Comment: It currently doesn't have a posted_at column, how would I go about creating one to implement this?

Comment: Added Post Model to question

Comment: Then you can use the `created_at` column, i guess. It does not really matter, you can order with any column you like.

Comment: Is this a method in the controller? What should I put in my view to display them?

Comment: It depends on your application but i guess it can be something like `@recent_posts = Post.where.not(id: @post.id).order('posted_at desc').limit(6)` and in your view: `@recent_posts.each do |post| ...`